# C# Binding variables between classes

Tags: c#, mvvm

Is it possible to bind a variable from one class to another variable in another class?

I am implementing MVVM in a windows phone 8.1 app and I am new to windows phone. What I am trying to do is: I have one Model with a DateTime Property and I want to get the value of that property transfer it to the code behind of my mainpage.xaml.cs calculate the elapsed time and display the elapsed time to the UI.

I have tried somethings but without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"transfer it to the code behind of my mainpage.xaml.cs"* is not MVVM. In MVVM, your ViewModel has properties and you bind them in your View.

Here, you could create a ViewModel with a property `TimeSpan ElapsedTime` (with the usual change notification), and automatically update (recalculate) it every second using a timer such as `DispatcherTimer`.